# What is the worst case running time for this method?

Tags: java, hashmap, runtime

```
    public String mostFrequent(){
        int a = 0; Set s = hm.keySet(); String r = ""; 
        Iterator<String> itrs = s.iterator();
        while (itrs.hasNext()){
            String b = itrs.next(); 
            if (hm.get(b) > a){ 
                a = hm.get (b);
                r = b;
            }
        }
   return r;
```

I know the worst case running time of get(v) is o(n). Then is the worst case running time of this method o(n^3), since it uses get(b) twice in a while loop? I am not sure what I think is correct or not. 
Thanks for any kinds of hints and explanation!

Comment: You need to make at least an attempt at your own problem (and this looks like homework). Explain the analysis you've done so far and your reasoning.

Comment: This might help: O(N) + O(N) = O(N) **;** O(N) * O(N) = O(N^2)

Comment: If `hm` is a hash map, it's not true that `get()` is `O(n)`. It should be `O(1)`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing here. Most frequent key? It's isomorphic. Also, I suggest you look at `hm.entrySet()`.

Comment: @AlexD - hash is WORST case O(N) - average case is 1 - question asks about worst case

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to read few chapters of Cormen or Tamassia. Let us visit your problem statement.

1) The operations on Hashmap must be ideally constant time(although they depend on the load factor), we can safely assume that it is constant time here i.e. O(1).

2) The keySet method generally is a O(n) time operation.

3) Inside the while loop, you are just doing a lookup, comparison and an assignment, all of these are primitive operations with O(1) running time.

4) Moreover, in the while loop you should not use the get method twice, doesn't make much sense, you could have just used it once and stored the value in another variable.

If all these arguments make sense to you, you can safely say that the running time would be T(n) = O(n) + c1 O(1) + c2 O(1) + C3 O(1)

You can safely drop the lower order terms and the constants to get T(n) = O(n)

If you really want to understand these things, you can always visit my [blog](http://techieme.in/asymptotic-analysis/)

Comment: O() is worst case - you cannot assume that hashmap is O(1) it is average case 1

Comment: I said, it depends on the load factor... Moreover, he is using Java and I am sure he has not overridden the hashcode and equals... So it will be O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helpful way to visualize O()

```
Imagine 1000 things

If you have an outer loop of 1000 times
        doing 1000 things thats 1,000,000 things = O(N^2)

If you do 1000 loops that is O(N)

If you do 10 loops that is O(log(N))

If you don't loop that is O(1)

Multiplying or dividing O() by any constant does nothing

O() of a sequence of things is the O() of the biggest thing in the sequence

Every level of Loops multiplies O() by N
```

Guestimate how many things you do when N=1000 and that will give you the right order of magnitude